# intellij 9 + griffon 0.9.5 dsl script execution error?

Tags: intellij-idea, griffon

dsl script execution error
 No signature of method:griffon.annotateScope() is applicable for argment types:(java.util.linkedHashMap) values:[ctype.griffon.transform.EventPublisher]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSL is intended to be used with Intellij IDEA 11 or newwer. Older versions of Intellij are not supported.

Comment: intellij 11 create griffon project cannot generate griffon project structure because JDK is not specified for module "AddressBook" .Griffon project will not be created if you don't specify JDK.Do you want to spcify JDK?